# Immersive mode on splash screen

Tags: android, splash-screen, statusbar

I'm trying to implement a splash screen that takes the whole screen. So, the Status Bar needs to be hidden, but only during the splash screen.
Right now the splash screen shows up but the status bar is still shown too.
I tried this approach with no success:

```
public class LaunchScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);

        startActivity(new Intent(LaunchScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

This is my splash resource file:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
</style>
```

launch_screen.xml:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</item>
```

manifest file:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".LaunchScreen"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: you can make it transparent and your splash image below it

Comment: @AhmedAbd-Elmeged What part can I make transparent?

Comment: is this the shape you would like to be if yes i will answer the question

Comment: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/79c0744da419fd365cfe94431c77fa27223fc96f/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f576e4d355772302e706e67

Comment: @AhmedAbd-Elmeged the answer is yes and no. I see your background takes on the whole screen, which is what I want, but I don't want the time or all those notification icons on the top (status bar) to be displayed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case, someone finds it helpful, I added the following lines in my style file:

```
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

then removed these lines from LauncherScreen class:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

Now it workds like a charm!